# JSON cannot de-serialize Xamarin weather app

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm learning how to do lists in Xamarin, I started yesterday and I have a work to complete by the next few days. My first app worked well but the second one (is mainly based on the first one, I had a class which was 1:30 hours long and didn't get much out there), when I run my new program on Android I get the error that it cannot deserialize.

I'm pretty sure my mistake is in MainPage.xaml.cs

meteo0.cs (line 8 to 26)

```
public class Meteo0
{
    public string precipitaProb { get; set; }
    public int tMin { get; set; }
    public int tMax { get; set; }
    public string predWindDir { get; set; }
    public int idWeatherType { get; set; }
    public int classWindSpeed { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public int classPrecInt { get; set; }
    public int globalIdLocal { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string forecastDate { get; set; }
    public List<Meteo0> data { get; set; }
    public DateTime dataUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs(line 10 to 39)

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    const string Url = "https://api.ipma.pt/open-data/forecast/meteorology/cities/daily/1110600";

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        GetMeteo0();
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
    async void GetMeteo0()
    {
        List<Meteo0> meteo0;
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Url);
        meteo0 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Meteo0>>(content);
        meteo0ListView.ItemsSource = meteo0;
    }
    private void meteo0ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Meteo0 meteo0 = e.SelectedItem as Meteo0;
        Navigation.PushAsync(new MeteoDetails(meteo0));
    }
}
```

editted MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    const string Url = "https://api.ipma.pt/open-data/forecast/meteorology/cities/daily/1110600";

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        GetMeteo0();
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
    async void GetMeteo0()
    {
        List<Meteo0> meteo0;
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Url);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
        meteo0ListView.ItemsSource = result.data;
    }
    private void meteo0ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Meteo0 meteo0 = e.SelectedItem as Meteo0;
        Navigation.PushAsync(new MeteoDetails(meteo0));
    }
}
```

editted meteo0.cs

```
public class Meteo0
{
    public string precipitaProb { get; set; }
    public double tMin { get; set; }
    public double tMax { get; set; }
    public string predWindDir { get; set; }
    public int idWeatherType { get; set; }
    public int classWindSpeed { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public int classPrecInt { get; set; }
    public int globalIdLocal { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
}
```

new RootObject.cs

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string forecastDate { get; set; }
    public List<Meteo0> data { get; set; }
    public DateTime dataUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="meteo0ListView" ItemSelected="meteo0ListView_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="Weather"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: What is the actual error message and stacktrace?

Comment: `<TextCell Text="Weather"/>` Is this your data binding ? if yes,you should use `<TextCell Text="{Binding property}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Json result received from the server, you can see that it's not actually a list in the root. What you're trying to do, is to cast a single object into a List even though the list of data points is actually a property within the root object.

```js
{  
   "owner":"IPMA",
   "country":"PT",
   "data":[  
      {  
         "precipitaProb":"79.0",
         "tMin":"11.3",
         "tMax":"17.7",
         "predWindDir":"SW",
         "idWeatherType":7,
         "classWindSpeed":2,
         "longitude":"-9.1286",
         "forecastDate":"2019-02-10",
         "classPrecInt":1,
         "latitude":"38.7660"
      },
      {  
         "precipitaProb":"0.0",
         "tMin":"9.6",
         "tMax":"17.0",
         "predWindDir":"N",
         "idWeatherType":1,
         "classWindSpeed":1,
         "longitude":"-9.1286",
         "forecastDate":"2019-02-11",
         "latitude":"38.7660"
      }
      // ...
   ],
   "globalIdLocal":1110600,
   "dataUpdate":"2019-02-10T11:31:03"
}
```

Knowing this, you should probably have two classes, the main one containing the list of data points. Something like this:

```cs
public class WeatherResult {
    public string owner {get; set; }
    public string country {get; set; }
    public List<Meteo0> data { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Then, you should deserialize to that one instead of a List of Meteo0 entities.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherResult>(content);
```

After this, you can easily use the List of Meteo0 objects as an ItemsSource by referring to `result.data`.

By the way, as you can see from the data, tMin and tMax fields are not of type integer because they have decimal values in them. You'll have to fix that one too.

Comment: Hi hankide, thanks for the fast awnser, i edited my code but im sure i have somethings wrong, can you have a look to the editted files and the new one? Thanks

Comment: @RuiLima Check out the last part of my answer. You should change the type of tMin and tMax to be something that supports decimal values (float, double, decimal) instead of an integer. Otherwise the deserialization of a value like 9.6 will fail.

Comment: done but i still dont get the values on the app, the app works, and i can select the menus but i cant get the values

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Do you mean that you can't visually see anything on the UI after binding the list to the ItemsSource? If that's the case, you should also post MainPage.xaml in your question. Otherwise, have you checked with the debugger whether `result.data` contains any items?

Comment: When i start the app i have a menu that i can click in and i go to the page that suposly gives me the weather info, the info does not appear, i will post my mainpage.xaml above

Comment: I bet my mistake is on the MainPage.xaml.cs near '            meteo0ListView.ItemsSource = result.data;' can you check please? I put a break point in that line but the code does not run that

Comment: Ok, if you put a break point on `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);`, does that work? Are there any errors that you might be missing, since it looks like that ItemsSource is never set? If I understood correctly, you can't see any items on the ListView?

Comment: Hi @hankide, it doenst work even with the break point, no items seen on list view, i dont know about itemsource, thanks in advance